# Converting string to Columns with if condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to create columns based on the integer value. There are two scenarios. Weekdays are starting from either 0 or 1. So I am trying to figure it out how to apply logic to create columns out of the data provided.

Expected output is

```
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
1    0   0   0   0   0   0
0    0   0   0   0   1   0
0    1   1   1   0   0   1
```

Comment: `TOP` is not supported by MySQL, you should to use `LIMIT`

Comment: Please provide the table structure and sample data [mre]

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev provided for your perusal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `LIKE` condition for this problem:

```
SELECT top 1000
    Working,
    CASE WHEN Working LIKE '%1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Mon,
    CASE WHEN Working LIKE '%2%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Tue,
    CASE WHEN Working LIKE '%3%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Wed,
    CASE WHEN Working LIKE '%4%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Thu,
    CASE WHEN Working LIKE '%5%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Fri,
    CASE WHEN Working LIKE '%6%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Sat,
    CASE WHEN Working LIKE '%7%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Sun
from WorkingTable;
```

[SQLize - sql code online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/83c3b9c58a9d57bdaf18a8099a932f90/)

Comment: Thank you so much. Again I have a new question for you. I've updated my question above. There is a section ```New Question. If the WorkingTable has the following data``` where the new question begins.. I'd appreciate your feedbacks.

Comment: https://sqlize.online/s/ln